# Using torch mode on all devices/APIversion

Tags: android

I'm developping a simple torch app. The button is in the notiffication drawer (with multiple aother buttons, like wifi ON/OFF, go to phone settings etc ...)

This code :

```
 camera = Camera.open();
 Camera.Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
 p.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
 camera.setParameters(p);
 camera.startPreview();
```

Works fine on a lot of device, even on lollipop.
But it doesn't work on my Nexus 5 (version android 5.1).

Itried using the new Camera2 api, but it throw a Verrification Error on devices that don't run lollipop.

Do you have any idea how to fix this please ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a preview surface before you can start preview. Some devices (unfortunately) allow for this to work, which leads to confusion, but the API requires a Surface or a SurfaceTexture to be set up as a preview target before you can start preview.

You can just create a dummy SurfaceTexture, if you don't want to display the preview in your app.